# Android Uiautomator doesn't see elements inside game application

Tags: java, appium, android-uiautomator

I'm trying to test android game apps from play store.
Using Java+Appium.
For detecting elements I'm using uiautomatorviewer. He see all andoid menu..
But he doesnt see separated elements inside the game. He sees only one big element.
What should I do? Example below:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvWCJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You see only *one big element* because it's is a single custom View implementing game UI.

Comment: And how I can find each element in this case? 
Appium useless in this case?

Comment: They are not Views, so Views based tools won't help.